# Flet: How to send a pubsub broadcast message from outside

Tags: python, flet

I'm building a flet application that will be used to command a hardware device and display data received from the device.

[image: Block Diagram]

In addition to a desktop application, I would also like to give multiple users access using a web app with multiple sessions.
I have a class instance in a global scope that interfaces to the hardware. For commanding (sending data to the hardware) the sessions call the write function of the class using a lock for thread safety (blue arrows). For the opposite direction (receiving data from the hardware) I currently use a similar mechanism where a click event in the sessions calls a read function (again using a lock) which then requests data from the hardware and returns it to the sessions with the function return value.

Now I want to implement periodic data requests from the hardware. I don't want each session to periodically read data using the mechanism described above because that would send 3 data requests to the hardware, receive 3 replies, and return them to the corresponding sessions (for 3 sessions as in the diagram). Instead, I would like to have a periodic timer in my interface class (a periodic thread) that would send 1 request to the hardware, receive the reply, and then broadcast the data to all sessions using pubsub (red arrows).

Is there a way I can use pubsub outside of the flet application (in the timer thread) to send a broadcast message to the sessions? Or could there be a headless session, a page that is not showing anything and is not starting a web server in which I can embed my interface class and use its page.pubsub.send_all() function to do the broadcast?
If possible I would like the same code to work as a desktop app.

I tried to use a pubsub instance from the flet package but realized that it needs a websocket connection to communicate to the sessions and I don't know how to set this up.
I also thought about using another session of my app which has a big if-then-else statement in there to make the first session/instance the matter instance which exclusively talks to the hardware and then communicates to other instances. The problem I see with that is that this session could be closed and then the other sessions would be orphans and have no way of communicating with the hardware.

**Edit**

Here is a minimalist example to help understand what I'm looking for

```
import flet as ft
from datetime import datetime
import threading

class PeriodicThread(object):
    def __init__(self, callback=None, period=1, name=None, *args, **kwargs):
        self.name = name
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.callback = callback
        self.period = period
        self.stop = False
        self.current_timer = None
        self.schedule_lock = threading.Lock()

    def set_period(self, period):
        self.period = period
        
    def start(self):
        self.stop = False
        self.schedule_timer()

    def run(self):
        if self.callback is not None:
            self.callback(*self.args, **self.kwargs)

    def _run(self):
        try:
            self.run()
        except Exception as e:
            pass
        finally:
            with self.schedule_lock:
                if not self.stop:
                    self.schedule_timer()

    def schedule_timer(self):
        self.current_timer = threading.Timer(self.period, self._run, *self.args, **self.kwargs)
        if self.name:
            self.current_timer.name = self.name
        self.current_timer.start()

    def cancel(self):
        with self.schedule_lock:
            self.stop = True
            if self.current_timer is not None:
                self.current_timer.cancel()

    def join(self):
        self.current_timer.join()


class hardware_interface():
    def __init__(self):
        self.lock = threading.Lock()
        self.cnt = 0
        self.timer = PeriodicThread(callback=self.cb_timer, period=1, name="timer_periodic_update")
        self.timer.start()
        
    def send_command(self, cmd, cmd_data):
        print(f'Instrument: executing command "{cmd} {cmd_data}"')
        
    def read_oneoff_data(self):
        data = self.cnt
        self.cnt += 1
        print(f'Instrument: data requested, replied {data}')
        return data
    
    def cb_timer(self):
        data = datetime.now()
        print(f'Instrument: data requested, replied {data}')
        #TODO: Send broadcast message with the data to all app sessions
        #      If this would be a flet page object I could use
        #      self.pubsub.send_all(data)


class App(ft.UserControl):
    def build(self):
        
        self.tf_cmd = ft.TextField(label="CMD")
        self.tf_cmd_data = ft.TextField(label="CMD Data")
        self.tf_req_data = ft.TextField(label="Requested Data")
        self.tf_per_data = ft.TextField(label="Periodic Data")
        
        page = ft.Column(
            [
                ft.Row(
                    [
                        self.tf_cmd,
                        self.tf_cmd_data,
                        ft.ElevatedButton(text="Send Command", on_click=self.btn_send_click)
                    ]
                ),        
                ft.Row(
                    [
                        self.tf_req_data,
                        ft.ElevatedButton(text="Request Data", on_click=self.btn_reqdata_click)
                    ]
                ),
                ft.Row(
                    [
                        self.tf_per_data
                    ]
                )
            ]
        )
        self.page.pubsub.subscribe(self.on_HW_periodic_data_msg)
        return page
    
    
    def btn_send_click(self, e):
        g_hw_if.lock.acquire(timeout=3)
        g_hw_if.send_command(self.tf_cmd.value, self.tf_cmd_data.value)
        g_hw_if.lock.release()
        
    def btn_reqdata_click(self, e):
        g_hw_if.lock.acquire(timeout=3)
        self.tf_req_data.value = g_hw_if.read_oneoff_data()
        g_hw_if.lock.release()
        self.update()
        
    def on_HW_periodic_data_msg(self, msg):
        self.tf_per_data.value = msg
        self.update()


def session_main(page: ft.Page):
    app = App()
    page.add(app)


def main():
    global g_hw_if

    g_hw_if = hardware_interface()
    ft.app(target=session_main, view=ft.WEB_BROWSER, port=45678)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If I run this code a tab with the web app will open in my browser. I open another tabs and enter the same URL as in the first one to start a new session of the web app.
Now I can send a command to the simulated instrument (class hardware_interface) by entering e.g. "loglevel" in the CMD textbox, "3" in the CMD Data textbox and then clicking the "Send command" button in either of the tabs. Similarly each session can request data from the simulated instrument by clicking the "Request Data" button.
The class hardware_interface has a timer callback function which periodically requests data from the instrument. What I'm looking for is a way to send the data I get in the callback to all sessions of the flet app (at the #TODO comment). If the hardware_interface class would be a flet page then I could use self.pubsub.send_all(data) but it isn't.

Comment: Please share a minimum workable code example

Comment: There is probably a way, and there likely could be - those are not the answers you're looking for, but without specific code or a more specific question, I doubt you'll get more specific answers. Have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I updated my question and added example code.

Comment: If anybody has an idea of a way I could investigate, please let me know!

Comment: I found a solution. It is shown [here](https://github.com/flet-dev/flet/discussions/2764).